# Rewrite a Bash script to php?

Tags: php

how would I rewrite this as a php script. also if anyone knows of a better way other than LAME please let me know.

```
for i in *.wav; do
    lame -h -b 192 "$i" "${i%.wav}.mp3"
done
```

Comment: Why would you use this in PHP? You could simply call this shell script using [`exec()`](http://php.net/exec) or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward rewrite would be:

```
<?php
foreach(glob('*.wav') as $i){
   exec('lame -h -b 192 ' . escapeshellarg($i) . ' ' . escape_shellarg(basename($i, '.wav') . '.mp3'));
}
```

Of course, it offers no advantage over your shell script ;-)

**Edit:** I'm not proficient with bash but I suspect `${i%.wav}` may remove the `.wav` suffix; I've changed the PHP code accordingly.

Comment: It'll execute `sh -c` once for each file too. It's small overhead compared to running lame of course, but it is wasted heat. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [glob](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).

```
foreach (glob("*.wav") as $filename) {
..code ..
}
```

Comment: so within the glob I can insert the Bash statement

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to execute the `lame` command in the shell anyway, so there is no use for this. If you need to kick the processing of from php, just execute the whole script from php.

Comment: +1 Good point. Still, he may want to control the list of files from within PHP to interact with the user or something, so @AntonioCS's answer applies too